# Data position fixed doesn't work using jquery mobile in BlackBerry

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, web

When i tried to keep header and footer to be fixed on the mobile device using tha data-position fixed it seems working on the android device but not on blackberry.

Header and footer gets disappeared on using the data-position fixed on black berry whereas it works appropriately on other platform.

```
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try adding `data-tap-toggle="false"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I works we need to add to the css

```
[data-role=footer]{bottom:0;right:0;top:auto! important ;position:absolute !important; } 
[data-role=header]{top:0; position:absolute !important; bottom: auto !important;}
```

Comment: why do you `!important` every rule?

Comment: what is the use of Important rlemon answer is in it only.

Comment: If you only need to fix your footer and its width is not covering all page width, try with: 
``[data-role=footer]{bottom:0;right:0;top:auto! important ;position:absolute !important; width: 100%!important;}``

Answer (score 3):

Simply add this data attribute `data-tap-toggle="false"` in header.

```
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

[The Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-options.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was searching for! :)

Answer (score 0):

What BlackBerry device do you have? In Jquery Mobile the fixed toolbars are only fixed to top on devices that support fixed positioning.

[The documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) says fixed toolbars should work on "most desktop browsers, iOS5+, Android 2.2+, BlackBerry 6, and others".

Comment: am using blackberry curve 9380 simulator

Answer (score 0):

On my Android phone (Galaxy S with Android 2.3.3), their demo pages fixed footers and headers don't work at all - as soon as I try to scroll they move with me, then re-affix themselves. If I just touch the screen they disappear, if I touch the screen again they reappear!

[Check this doc from jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/#/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html).

sames goes for the 1.1.1 version of the demo. The demo works fine in Chrome browser on my desktop though.

Answer (score 0):

the most easy way is to remove the user-scalable=no from your viewport
and set

```
minimum-scale=1.0
maximum-scale=1.0
```

more on this matter here
http://wil.to/android-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

thats a feature in android, possibly other browsers as well, to clear header and footer elements allowing full screen display of the page, it's surposed to happen.